# Python dictionary iterator performance

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, python-internals

When working with dictionaries in Python, [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) says that the time complexity of iterating through the element of the dictionary is `O(n)`, where `n` is the largest size the dictionary has been.

However, I don't think that there is an obvious way to iterate through the elements of a hash table. Can I assume good performance of `dict.iteritems()` when iterating through element of a hash table, without too much overhead?

Since dictionaries are used a lot in Python, I assume that this is implemented in some smart way. Still, I need to make sure.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you're interested in how dictionaries are implemented, check out [*"the mighty dictionary"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68).

Comment: It's not clear what type of answer you are looking for. You can assume good performance, until it is too slow for your needs.

Comment: A hash table is nothing more than an array, indexed by hash values.  There's nothing hard about iterating over the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [notes on Python's dictionary source code](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/dictnotes.txt), I think the relevant points are the following:

> Those methods (iteration and key listing) loop over every potential entry

How many potential entries will there be, as a function of largest size (largest number of keys ever stored in that dictionary)?  Look at the following two sections in the same document:

> Maximum dictionary load in PyDict_SetItem.  Currently set to 2/3
>
> Growth rate upon hitting maximum load. Currently set to *2.

This would suggest that the sparsity of a dictionary is going to be somewhere around 1/3~2/3 (unless growth rate is set to *4, then it's 1/6~2/3).  So basically you're going to be checking upto 3 (or 6 if *4) potential entries for every key.

Of course, whether it's 3 entries or 1000, it's still O(n) but 3 seems like a pretty acceptable constant factor.

Incidentally here are the rest of the source & documentation, including that of the DictObject:

http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/